# Anyone having issues with "Package Not Found" messages?

Tags: managed-package, developer-edition, enterprise

> This package can’t be installed. There are problems that prevent this
> package from being installed.
>
> The requested package doesn't yet exist or has been deleted. If this
> is a recently created package version, please try again in a few
> minutes or contact the package publisher.

At 2:25 PM EST I successfully uploaded a managed package (first gen). However, I cannot install it anywhere (nor a sandbox, nor a developer org).  Anyone else having similar issues?  I even changed the status from Beta to Released to see if it made any difference.  None.

I would like to know if this is a propagation issue and I just will have to wait out.

Comment: Something SF changed has been slowing down the propagation. In the past I almost never ran into this issue but it is a daily occurrence now. Just letting you know that you are not alone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I even changed the status from Beta to Released to see if it made any difference

This is a very dangerous tactic on a 1GP. You've now incurred component lock-in and manageability rules on everything you included in that beta package.

> I would like to know if this is a propagation issue and I just will have to wait out.

This error is virtually always a propagation issue and in the vast majority of cases self-resolves after a period of time. I would recommend you open a case if it's not resolved after tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you @DavidReed

Comment: Problem solved.  It was a propagation issue. It took 4 hours to become available.